# How to set time limit for request processing time of http request(kestrel, asp.net core)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to limit max time of http request processing in asp.net core(sever kestrel) . How can i do that?

For example method `DoSomething` in controller below

```
Controller{
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public async Task<string> DoSomething(){
       await Task.Delay(rnd.next(200));
       return "some result";
    }
}
```

should stop processing if processing time > 100 ms.

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding your question you want to cancel a process that might take a long time. This would be achieved by either using a `CancellationToken` or wrapping the process in a task and then killing the task

Comment: @MindSwipe, thanks. I thought about manual task management. But may be kestrel already has possibility to set max request time using some settings for that. I trying to find any info about that.